# Solving an improper integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have come across this integral and have been unable to solve it so far.

$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{0.29881}e^{-0.5x^2}\,\mathrm dx$$

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](https://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](https://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: See the error function.  It is the CDF of the gaussian function (which is similar to what you have in your problem).

Answer (score 2):

This integral cannot be solved by hand. But it is related to the normal distribution or error function. You can look this up in tables. Numerical integration is possible by e.g. Gauss-Quardature, after splitting the integral into two pieces. From $-\infty$ to zero and from zero to your upper bound. The integral from $-\infty$ to 0 has a value that is known to be $\sqrt{2\pi}$ ([Computing Some Integrals via Gauss Integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118956/computing-some-integrals-via-gauss-integral)).

Answer (score 2):

Substitute $u=\dfrac{x\sqrt 2}{2}$ to solve the indefinite integral:
$$\int e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\mathrm d x= \sqrt\frac{\pi}{2}\int\frac{2e^{-u^2}}{\sqrt\pi}\,\mathrm d u= \sqrt\frac{\pi}{2}\mathrm{erf}\,u=\sqrt\frac{\pi}{2}\mathrm{erf}\left( \frac{x\sqrt 2}{2}\right)$$
Thus
$$I:=\int_{-\infty}^{0.29881} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\,\mathrm dx=\sqrt\frac{\pi}{2}\mathrm{erf}\left( \frac{0.29881\sqrt 2}{2}\right)-\lim_{x\to -\infty}\sqrt\frac{\pi}{2}\mathrm{erf}\left( \frac{x\sqrt 2}{2}\right)$$
and since $\mathrm{erf}(-\infty)=-1$,
$$I= \sqrt\frac{\pi}{2}\mathrm{erf}\big( 0.149405\sqrt 2\big)+\sqrt\frac{\pi}{2}=\boxed{\sqrt\frac{\pi}{2}\Big( \mathrm{erf}\big(0.149405\sqrt 2\big)+1\Big)}\approx 1.5477$$

Comment: Thank you so much . It was correct answer. Fantastic work .